# How to get hostname for dynamodb in AWS and NOT local?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the AWS sdk for java and am trying to instantiate an AmazonDynamodb instance so that I can connect to Dynamodb on AWS. I find the docs very frustrating because I have only seen how to do it locally. Thats no problem. How do you get the hostname of a dynamodb that is deployed in AWS? Any assistance that points to documentation that explains how to get this (As it is not visible in the console in my experience) or if somebody could just tell me. It would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you crossing regions? Why do you need a hostname?

Comment: Im assuming that I do because thats how it works with Aurora for example and the dynamodb docs also show thats how its done for running the local dynamodb.... But youre saying that is not necessary? And jsut creating an instance will give my client access provided the permissions are set properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for hostnames you can get it from,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

If you are connecting to dynamodb in the same region, sdk knows to configure itself with region and with the type of resource sdk need to access. You don't need to configure the endpoint unless you are connecting to different region.

**Same Region:**

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);

Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("ProductCatalog");

// Build the item
Item item = new Item()
    .withPrimaryKey("Id", 123)
    .withString("Title", "Bicycle 123")
    .withString("Description", "123 description")
    .withString("BicycleType", "Hybrid")
    .withString("Brand", "Brand-Company C");

// Write the item to the table 
PutItemOutcome outcome = table.putItem(item);
```

**Different Region:** (In this case it is Asia Pacific (Singapore))

> AmazonDynamoDB client =
>   AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration( new
>   AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://dynamodb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com",
>   "ap-southeast-1")) .build();

Hope it helps.